# Получать уведомления windows python

Tags: python, уведомления

Час добрый 

Подскажите пожалуйста какими методами можно получать уведомления windows?

Нужно отслеживать все уведомления, которые приходят в данное меню  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при получении каких либо уведомлений, выводить в консоль название приложения, отправившего уведомление и текст уведомления

Как пример при получении следующих уведомлений: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоль должно вывестись 3 записи с названием приложения и текстом уведомлений
\